# C# enctypted .accdb connection

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2007, oledb

I recently updated my database from .mdb (MS Access 2003) to .accdb (MS Access 2010).

With this update I also updated my provider from: `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

The connection works ok when I use a .accdb file without a password, but once I choose to

> Encrypt with Password

I receive the following error when I try to open a connection.

> Cannot open database ''. It may not be a database that your
>   application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt.

Used connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\\App\\Main\\bin\\Debug\\db.xxx;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password=MyPass;
```

Note: I use a custom extension for my .accdb file, this was used for .mdb files without problems and I assume this should not be a problem (tested).

Comment: There have been reports of problems with password longer than 14 characters. Also that some characters might cause trouble. Try changing password to a short one with normal characters. If you are using the password you have shown - the above is clearly no help to you! :]

Comment: Password is shorter than 10 chars :) ... Thanks for the tip though

Comment: Stange one. Good luck, if I think of any thing, like Arnie "I'll be back"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your connection string.  Still I would try it from VBA to see whether that effort sheds any light on the problem.

This one worked from Access 2007 whether I named the db file with "accdb" or "xxx" file extension.  The single quotes are not required around my password; the code succeeded whether or not I included the single quotes.

```
Public Sub OleDbToEncryptedAccdb()
    'Const cstrDb As String = "encryptd.accdb" '
    Const cstrDb As String = "encryptd.xxx"
    Const cstrFolder As String = "C:\share\Access"
    Const cstrPassWord As String = "letmein"
    Dim cn As Object
    Dim strConnect As String

    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        cstrFolder & Chr(92) & cstrDb & _
        ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password='" & cstrPassWord & "';"
    Debug.Print strConnect
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cn.ConnectionString = strConnect
    cn.Open
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Edit**: Apparently Access 2010 provides a stronger encryption method than earlier Access versions.  With `db.xxx` open in Access 2010, check which ACE version is used as the `Provider`.

```
? CurrentProject.Connection.Provider
```

If it replies something like `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.14.0`, use that in your c# connection string.

Comment: Thanks for the sample.

I have tried to init a connection with this connection string from PowerShell but I have the same results.

Surely I am doing something wrong

Comment: Start Access and see whether you can still open `db.xxx`.  Perhaps it is corrupted as the error message suggests.  Make sure you try that from the same user account which runs the failing c# code.

Comment: I'm guessing this is due to the encryption method.  Access 2010 can open it, but Access 2007 can't.  However I haven't used Access 2010, so I'm only speculating ... but see whether the edit to my answer points you to something useful.